How to Reduce Live Streaming Latency in VLC Media Player with Flutter?
I'm working on a live streaming application using Flutter and VLC Media Player. The setup works, but I'm experiencing significant latency (about 3-5 seconds) in the live stream. I need to reduce this latency to make the streaming more real-time.
What I've Tried:

Adjusted the caching settings in VLC:
VlcPlayerController controller = VlcPlayerController.network(
    videoStreamURL ?? '',
    hwAcc: HwAcc.full,
    autoPlay: true,
    options: VlcPlayerOptions(
      rtp: VlcRtpOptions([VlcRtpOptions.rtpOverRtsp(true)],),
    ), //
  );



Ensured low-latency network conditions and tested on a high-speed connection.
Searched through VLC and Flutter documentation, but couldn't find specific guidelines for reducing live stream latency.

Environment:

Flutter version: 3.22.0
flutter_vlc_player: 7.4.1

Error Messages:
There are no specific error messages, but the latency remains around 3-5 seconds.
Question:
What are the best practices for reducing live streaming latency in VLC Media Player when using Flutter? Are there specific configurations or code adjustments that can help achieve lower latency?

How low of latency do you need?  Much lower and you're going to need to be tuning the TX end also.  Also, what system and output API are you using?  All of that comes into play if you're trying to get extremely low latency.

@Brad Our device uses FFmpeg to push live video via the RTSP protocol to the Wowza streaming engine. We then play the live stream in our mobile app using VLC Player with the RTSP protocol from Wowza. Currently, we are experiencing a delay of around 3 to 4 seconds.
We need to reduce the latency to less than 1 second.

Are you sure you need latency that low?  You're going to have to make a lot of tradeoffs in quality, reliability, and cost to do that at any reasonable scale.  WebRTC is pretty much your only choice if that's what you actual need.
